# How can i know which query takes long time while running a postgres function?

Tags: postgresql

Actually i am running a function in `postgres` which takes 1123 + ms to execute the function.

That function consist of calling other function and have many query to execute . How can i know which query is culprit for slow execution of function .

I have seen . `select * from pg_stat_activity;` give the output of current running process.

Can it is possible to get the individual query time while running the postgres function ?

I know many will say log the query time in database by insert but is there is any method in postgres so that i can get the time taking by each query .

Also is there is any way without changing the config file in postgres because i don't want to restart the postgres . If not , other solution most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not aware of any tool, but it would gives you a good idea to RAISE NOTICE current time after every step in function. will just give you a idea which query or sub function is taking long

Comment: Appropriated , but RAISE NOTICE is similar , having inserts after every query .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the [`pg_stat_statements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) extension, though loading it does require a server restart.

After installing it, just `SET pg_stat_statements.track = all` (as a superuser), call your function, then `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_statements`.

Unless you have exclusive access to the server, you probably want to include a default of `pg_stat_statements.track = none` in your `postgresql.conf`, so that only your session is tracked.